# Android - Populate values into already created POJO model object using retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a POJO model object "apiResponse" that has values from a previous API call.

```
{
   "status":200,
   "userModel":{
                 ...SOME VARIABLES...
               },
   "otherContentRelatedToUserModel":{
                    ..SOME RELATED CONTENT..
                    }
}
```

This apiResponse has an "UserModel" as an inner object.

**What i want to do** is pass this "apiResponse" object to another api call whose response is "UserModel", and have it update only the UserModel object in the APIResponse POJO object.

**The objective** is to keep a single source of related content, which could change based on the interaction in the application, but might not update the rest of the related content.

Or is it possible to atleast update an already created pojo model as a whole, updating the variable values in the model.?

**Reason for this ::**

The API's content does not change for a set amount of time in the server, mainly to avoid over traffic to the server. So some amount of logic has to be implemented on the application side. Currently using a DB is not really a viable option.

Basically update only a portion of the already created POJO class object with another api call.

Is this possible in android(kotlin) using retrofit? Or is there any other way this could be achievable?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to populate the additional fields in the existing `UserModel` object by using `Retrofit`, but you can do some magic with `GSON`:

```
data class UserModel(
        val userId: Int? = null,
        val userName: String? = null)

class OtherContentRelatedToUserModel

data class ApiResponsePojo(
        val status: Int? = null,
        val userModel: UserModel? = null,
        val otherContentRelatedToUserModel: OtherContentRelatedToUserModel? = null)

class UserModelInstanceCreator(var userModelToUpdate: UserModel? = null)
    : InstanceCreator<UserModel> {
    override fun createInstance(type: Type?): UserModel {
        return userModelToUpdate ?: UserModel()
    }
}

val apiResponseJson =
        """
            {
                "status":200,
                "userModel":{
                    "userId": 1
                },
                "otherContentRelatedToUserModel":{
                }
            }
        """

val userModelResponseJson =
        """
            {
                "userName": "john wick"
            }
        """

val userModelInstanceCreator = UserModelInstanceCreator()

val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(UserModel::class.java, userModelInstanceCreator)
        .create()

val apiResponse: ApiResponsePojo = gson.fromJson(apiResponseJson, ApiResponsePojo::class.java)
userModelInstanceCreator.userModelToUpdate = apiResponse.userModel
gson.fromJson(userModelResponseJson, UserModel::class.java)

...
// apiResponse.toString() result
// ApiResponsePojo(status=200, userModel=UserModel(userId=1, userName=john wick)...
```